# Eigenvalue of a matrix and a polynomial of that matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix over $F$, and let $c_1, ... c_n$ be its eigenvalues. Show that for every polynomial $g(x) \in F[x]$, the eigenvalues of $g(A)$ are $g(c_1), ... , g(c_n)$.

I think by making $A$ an upper triangular matrix the question might be solver easily. But I have no idea how to show how many times each eigenvalue has been repeated.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $g(x)= \sum_{k=0}^na_k x^k$ Then $$ Av_i=c_i v_i
\Rightarrow A^kv_i=c_i^k v_i $$

so that $$ g(A)v_i=(\sum_{k=0}^na_k A^k)v_i = \sum_{k=0}^na_k c_i^k
v_i=g(c_i)v_i $$

Answer (score 0):

We can write $A = P^{-1}DP$, with $D$ diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $P$ matrix of eigenvectors of corresponting eigenvalues.

Applying $g(x) = g_0 + g_1*x + ... + g_n*x^n$ polynomial to A we have

$ g(A) = g_0*P^{-1}P + g_1*P^{-1}DP + ... + g_n*P^{-1}D^nP$

$ g(A) = P^{-1}*(g_0 + g_1*D + ... + g_n*D^n)*P$

As D is diagonal, we can re-write it as

$ g(A) = P^{-1}g(D)P$ which leads the eigenvalues of $g(A)$ are $g(c_1),...,g(c_n)$